windows boot installation edit of cfg file
i tried to skip the cd key in the installation and version with this:
[EditionID]
Core
[Channel]
Retail
[VL]
0
now i have another problem it asks for the language pack, do you have any solution to skip the language pack too! and use the standard one.?
thank you

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
